# Agora - Peer to Peer video call in react native

Tags: react-native, agora.io

Hi fellow developers,

I want to implement peer-to-peer video calling in my react native app using agora SDK. I am using node and express.js. I have looked into several examples, but most of them are for live streaming . Can anyone guide me How should I implement it? and any guidance will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [example](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-RN-Quickstart/) which implements a video chat app.

To get the peer-to-peer calling functionality you can use this [library](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep) along with notifications.